# Need regular expression pattern that replaces variable value format

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string

I have variable called frequency which will have values like Monthly-YYYY or Quarterly-YYYY-Q1 or Annually-YYYY here YYYY is the year(2019).What I need is if I have value as Quarterly-YYYY-Q1 then it should be replaced as Quarterly-YYYY(Q1) .

Can someone help with any regex pattern that can be used here.Also Q1 is not fixed.It can be either Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4

```
if a="Quarterly-2019-Q2"
it should be replaced to
Quarterly-2019(Q1).
If anyother it should be as it is
```

Looking for some help on it.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Q2` in the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fairly simple using `replace`:

```js
const str = "Quarterly-2019-Q2";
const re = /-Q(\d)/;

const res = str.replace(re, "(Q$1)");

console.log(res);
```

Full string regex:

```js
const str = "Quarterly-2019-Q2";
const re = /Quarterly-(\d{4})-Q(\d)/;

const res = str.replace(re, "Quarterly-$1(Q$2)");

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Can you please share a reference document for this?

Comment: Reference document? For [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)? Or for something else?

Comment: For using regex to replace it as variable. The way you have used here `$1` to replace `\d{4}`.

Comment: what's the need of first capturing group?

Comment: To capture the year.

Comment: I wanted to know what's the need of that, not what it does:), why not just capture `(-Q\d)` and replace with `(Q$1)`?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean @AZ_. Edited.